# VS2010 intellisense outside scope, like SharpDevelop/Netbeans

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way of showing intellisense outside the current visible scope like for example Netbeans does in Java, and SharpDevelop?

To clarify: in SharpDevelop, say you need the class GZipStream, start typing and when the intellisense list empties, press ctrl+space, which completes the class. I like this behaviour when I forgot the exact class name. Is there such a function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing available in a *default* installation of Visual Studio to do that. The closest thing is the "Show Smart Tag" command (Ctrl+.) which enables you to automatically add a using statement, but you have to type the full name of the class. If you type `GZipStream` and then hit `Ctrl+.`, Visual Studio will suggest the namespace `System.IO.Compression` to add to the usings.

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does have this functionality. `Ctrl+Space` will autocomplete within the current scope, and `Ctrl+Alt+Space` will autocomplete within any scope, even if the namespace of the class being autocompleted is not currenlty imported.